# How to pas a struct containing an array ByVal to C++?

Tags: c++, vb6, interop

I am using a third party C++ dll which uses a function that has the following signature:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall CalcDDtable(struct ddTableDeal tableDeal, 
    struct ddTableResults * tablep);
```

The structs each contain just one fixed one dimensional array of `int`s (VB6 `Long`s). `tablep` will contain the results.

Had the C++ declaration  been:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall CalcDDtable(int * tableDeal, int * tablep);
```

then the VB6 `Declare` statement would have been:

```
Declare Function CalcDDtable Lib "my3rdParty.dll"(ByRef lngTable as Long,ByRef lngResult as Long) as int
This code would be called like:
Dim lngTables(15) As Long
Dim lngResults(20) As Long

'Initialize the lngTables array...

intResult=CalcDDtabel(lngTables(0),lngResults(0))
```

But I am at a loss how to declare the function above since the first array is packaged in a struct that is not a pointer.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe you need to recreate the structure in VB and then you can use that as it's byval, byref types in place of longs.

Comment: See the Microsoft [notes for developing dlls for VB6](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass structures by value from VB6 to a DLL. The tableDeal structure is by value (not a pointer) so I am not sure what you can do there.

You can pass structures by reference and they can contain fixed-length arrays, so your second arg would be ok. In fact if it *only* contains a fixed-length array of ints, you could just pass a fixed-length VB6 long array as in the second part of your question.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now. I could get hold of the source code and, not being held back by any deep understanding of C++, changed the method signature. It now works as the contents of the array was copied to a different array right away in the C++ method. The only thing that worries me is that I may have introduced a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

If structure is defined as :

```
struct ddTableDeal {
    int data[ ITEM_COUNT ];
};
```

Then AFAIK you can't call it in `VB` using array, because in `C/C++` size of this structure is `sizeof(int)*ITEM_COUNT`(may be even bigger for padding but in `VB` arrays are dynamic and will be allocated in heap using `SafeArrayCreate` or `SafeArrayCreateVector`, so size of those array of always fixed. I don't know `VB` well but if you can create structure in `VB` and use `ITEM_COUNT` of `int`(`Long` in `VB`) sequentially it may work but the best solution is to write a proxy function in `C/C++` that get variables from `VB`, create structure and call original function and then return result in `VB` provided buffer!

Comment: -1 Sorry, but with all respect this is **wrong**. VB6 *can* pass structures containing fixed-size arrays to C++. The runtime marshals them for you. See the [Microsoft notes on calling C++ DLLs from VB5/6](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp) if you wish to learn more.